# Is OpenTelemetry in Python safe to use with Async?

Tags: python, open-telemetry

I want to use OpenTelemetry with an Async application, and I want to be 101% sure that it will work as intended. Specifically, I'm worried about what happens with the `current_span` when we switch back and forth between asynchronous functions. I have this fear that if I rely on `tracer.start_as_current_span` to set the span in each function, and then I pass execution to another function which also sets the `current_span`, then when execution passes back to the first function it won't be tied to the correct span anymore.

Now, I have tried testing this a bit, and found no evidence that it breaks. But I also haven't found any documentation that says it explicitly won't break. Can anyone confirm?

I've done the following basic test, but I'm worried it misses something:

```
async def async_span():
    with tracer.start_as_current_span(name=f"span_{uuid.uuid4}") as span:
        for x in range(1000):
            assert trace.get_current_span() == span
            await asyncio.sleep(0.0001 * randint(1, 10))

async def main():
    with tracer.start_as_current_span(name="parent"):
        await asyncio.gather(*(async_span() for _ in range(10)))
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope, OpenTelemetry for Python is designed to consider asynchronous code. When you use `tracer.start_as_current_span` within an asynchronous context, the span becomes the current span for the duration of that context.

The key point is that the association of the current span is managed on a per-task basis. Asynchronous tasks in Python have their own context, and the asyncio event loop ensures that the task-local context is preserved when tasks switch back and forth.